# Delay animation with Transitions framework

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am trying to delay a transition using `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()` from the support library.

I want to use `AutoTransition` for make a `LinearLayout` appearing/disappearing. The animation works perfectly as expected, except that it is not delayed.

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootViewGroup, new AutoTransition().setStartDelay(1000));
linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The `linearLayout` is in the hierarchy of the `rootViewGroup` of course.

Comment: opened a ticket to the android team https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64139005

Answer (score 5):

I did some testing, but unfortunately I am also not able to make it work. It looks like the `setStartDelay` only works on the `ChangeBounds` transition.

See the following example (when you set the `startDelay` on the `first` transition, the delay won't work):

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLinearLayout);
mSceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
mStaggeredTransition = new TransitionSet();

Transition first = new Fade(Fade.OUT);
Transition second = new ChangeBounds();
Transition third = new Fade(Fade.IN);
second.setStartDelay(1000).addTarget(linearLayout);

mStaggeredTransition.setOrdering(ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL);
mStaggeredTransition.addTransition(first).addTransition(second).addTransition(third);

findViewById(R.id.testbutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mSceneRoot, mStaggeredTransition);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

So I suggest you to use something like this:

```
mSceneRoot.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootViewGroup, new AutoTransition().setStartDelay(1000));
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't really want to use `Handler` since I have to take care of potential memory leaks... but looks like it's the way to go. Thanks Jordy